# How to setup Syntastic as python3 checker instead of python2

Tags: vim, macvim, syntastic

In MacVim, I save following code as test.py

```
print "Hello world! python2"
```

, which is apparently wrong with python3, but
after I run :w to save the file, there is no error message for it,
Following is a part of ~/.vimrc, which is all about Syntastic:

```
" Syntastic                                                                     
"" Recommended settings                                                         
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#                                                   
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}                                    
set statusline+=%*                                                              
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1                                    
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1                                               
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1                                               

"" Display checker-name for that error-message                                  
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1        

"" I use the brew to install flake8                                             
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['flake8', 'python3']
```

How to make Syntastic detect this type of error as I run test.py in Terminal:

```
NingGW:Desktop ninggw$ python3 test.py
  File "test.py", line 1
    print "Hello world! python2"
                               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Following is what :SyntasticInfo said:

```
Syntastic version: 3.8.0-10 (Vim 800, Darwin, GUI)
Info for filetype: python
Global mode: active
Filetype python is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: flake8 python
Currently enabled checker: flake8
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Which Python installation does your `flake8` belong to? I think this is the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`flake8` is a Python package. It uses Python's built-in facilities to parse code, [so it accepts syntax for the Python version that it belongs to](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/).

How to install it for your `python3` installation depends on how that installation itself was installed - [unless you're fine with using `pip`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Oh, I just got it, brew install the flake8 to my python2! I reinstalled it with pip3 now...

Comment: It works! thanks! before I got your answer I tried pylint to solve it temporarily, now both pylint and flake8 point out the error, the former said `test.py|1 col 1 error| [syntax-error] Missing parentheses in call to 'print' [python/pylint]` and the latter `test.py|1 col 21 error| SyntaxError: invalid syntax [E999] [python/flake8]`

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqpython):

> **4.11. Q. How can I check scripts written for different versions of Python?**
>
> A. Install a Python version manager such as [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), activate the environment for the relevant version of Python, and install in it the checkers you want to use. Set `g:syntastic_python_checkers` accordingly in your `vimrc`, and run Vim from the virtual environment.
>
> If you're starting Vim from a desktop manager rather than from a terminal you might need to write wrapper scripts around your checkers, to activate the virtual environment before running the actual checks. Then you'll need to point the relevant `g:syntastic_python_<checker>_exec` variables to the wrapper scripts.